# xpages button - possible to change text or item while events are running?

Tags: xpages

Is it possible to change the text on an <xp:button> element when the code under the onclick event is running (and the partial refresh is not completed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPages way is to use the onStart and onComplete properties (there's also onError):

```
<xp:button value="Search" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" 
        onStart="changeText()" onComplete="unchangeText()">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:serverFunction();}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

You can pass the id of the button to the functions using "#{id:button1}" and use it to retrieve the button in CSJS.

Comment: this works excellent. I added a scriptblock: <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[function changeText(){
 $("button[id$=btnKurreUpdate]").attr("disabled", "true").addClass("disabled").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-fw"></i> Connnecting');
}

function unchangeText(){
 $("button[id$=btnKurreUpdate]").removeAttr("disabled").removeClass("disabled").html('Update from Kurre');
}
]]></xp:this.value>
   </xp:scriptBlock>

Answer (score 0):

We have something like that in place for our xp:button elements. We change the text and also add an FontAwesome "spinning wheel" until code is finished. At the start of our funtion we change text and icon, after code is finished - we revert to original xp:button text.
We use jQuery to modify the button element, basically you can to that with plain JavaScript (innerHTML) or dojo as well.

```
<xp:button value="Save" id="button-save" xp:key="submitSave">
   <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
      <xp:this.script><![CDATA[submitSaveFunction();]]></xp:this.script>
   </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>

submitSaveFunction {
$("button[id$=button-save]").attr("disabled", "true").addClass("disabled").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-fw"></i> Saving');
.....your code.....
$("button[id$=button-save]").removeAttr("disabled").removeClass("disabled").html('Save');
}
```

Comment: You can make another button (hidden) to run the partial refresh and SSJS and 'click' it in the submitSaveFunction code.

Comment: can you explain how I should implement the JS part?